# What is the opposite to "closed under an operation"?

Tags: terminology

A set is called closed under an operation if applying an operation on elements of a set always leads to an element of that set. But what about the opposite, when an operation on an element of the set *never* leads to an element of the set? Is there also a name for that?

Examples:

- The set of even numbers is closed under multiplication: The product of even numbers always is even.

  The set of primes is *???* under multiplication: The product of primes is *never* a prime.

  The set of single-digit numbers is neither closed nor *???* under multiplication: The product of two single-digit numbers may or may not be a single-digit number.
- The set of integers is closed under negation: The negation of an integer is always an integer.

  The set of positive numbers is *???* under negation: The negation of a positive number is never positive.

  The set of non-negative integers is neither closed nor *???* under negation: The negation of a non-negative number may or may not be non-negative.

Comment: I don't think there is a word. Anti-closed?

Comment: not an answer but related: in additive combinatorics one speaks about [sum-free sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-free_set).

Comment: "not closed under that operation"

Comment: @BrianO: No. The set of single digits is not closed under addition, but it is *not* *???* under addition.

Comment: Sorry, I was careless -- paid more attention to your headline than your question. As Arthur suggested, you may have to make up a term, and his suggested "anti-closed" is a pretty good one.